# How do you save on GTA 5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

The XBox360 is offline. I was very far in the missions. How do I save game in Grand Theft Auto 5?

Answer (score 0):

Two different ways:

1. In a safe house next to the bed, press right to sleep / save
2. If not in a safe house, press up to bring up the cell phone and then select quick save